# can I feed events into kinesis directly from firebase without a server in between

Tags: firebase, amazon-kinesis

I'd like to aggregate firebase events an a kinesis stream - is there a way to push events directly from firebase to kinesis without an intermediate server?  Can firebase trigger rest calls or kinesis feeds from a firebase event (on value, on add, on delete, etc...)